# GXEv3 U5 - Se generan request erroneos a /content/blank

Tags: genexus

Trabajando con el Upgrade 5 de GxEv3, encuentro en fiddler que se me están generando request innecesarios a /content/blank

[image: Fiddler]

Veo que esos request se genran porque en el form (MAINFORM) esta la acción así:
[image: MAINFORM]

Por otro lado, el único lugar donde aparece content/blank es en el gxgral.js:

```
        saveFormForAutoComplete:function(){
        if (gx.grid.drawAtServer || (gx.util.browser.isIE() && (gx.util.browser.isCompatMode() || document.documentMode <= 7 || gx.util.browser.ieVersion() <= 7) ))
            return;

        var GX_IFRAME_FFORM_AUTOC = 'gx_iframe_force_ajax_autocomplete';
        var form = gx.dom.form();

        var tmpIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        tmpIframe.id = GX_IFRAME_FFORM_AUTOC;
        tmpIframe.name = GX_IFRAME_FFORM_AUTOC;         
        tmpIframe.style.cssText = 'display: none';
        **tmpIframe.src="/content/blank";**
        document.body.appendChild(tmpIframe);
```

¿Este problema se introdujo en esta versión o estoy errando en algo?

Comment: Creo que deberías editar tu pregunta y mostrar código en lugar de imágenes. Como está ahora es imposible intentar revisar o reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema se introdujo en la versión XEv3 U5 y fue solucionado en U6 que saldrá en los próximos días.

Mientras tanto, se puede comentar el código de la función 'saveFormForAutoComplete' sin consecuencias para la aplicación.